# Possible dimensions of the intersection of three vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $R$ be a vector space of dimension $6$. Let  $A$, $B$, $C$ each be a subspace of dimension $4$. The pairwise intersection of these subspaces is of dimension $3$.

Now if we consider the intersection of all three of these subspaces, what are the possible dimensions that could be (e.g.,  $0,1,2,3$)

Answer (score 0):

It should be apparent that the greatest the dimension could be is 3 since otherwise the intersection $A \cap B$ would have dimension at least 4 for example. It is also apparent that the dimension can't be less than 2 since each pairwise intersection has dimension 3 and each subspace has dimension 4. From there, you should be able to convince yourself that it is possible for the intersection to have either dimension 2 or 3 by inspection.