# linear subspaces and their pairwise intersection

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $V_{1}, V_{2}, V_{3}$ are three linear subspaces in $\mathbb R^6$, each of them having dimension $4$, and each of their pairwise intersection has dimension $3$. What can be the dimension of intersection of them all?

Comment: What have you tried? Someone has posted the question already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455709/possible-dimensions-of-the-intersection-of-three-vector-subspaces).

Comment: frankly, i have a hard time imagining higher order dimensions so just used heuristics and logic and concluded that dimensions should be 2 or 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the following "inclusion-exclusion" principle:

$dim(span(U, V)) = dim(U) + dim(V) - dim(U \cap V)$

whenever we have subspaces $U, V \subseteq W$.

The equation easily generalises to

$dim(span(V_1, V_2, V_3)) = dim(V_1) + dim(V_2) + dim(V_3) - dim(V_1 \cap V_2) - dim(V_2 \cap V_3) - dim(V_3 \cap V_1) + dim(V_1 \cap V_2 \cap V_3)$

In this case, we have

$dim(span(V_1, V_2, V_3)) = 3 + dim(V_1 \cap V_2 \cap V_3)$

What are the possible dimensions of $span(V_1, V_2, V_3)$? Clearly, the dimension cannot exceed 6. Furthermore, we must have that the dimension is at least $dim(span(V_1, V_2)) = 5$. So the dimension is either 5 or 6. Both of these dimensions are possible: take $V_1, V_2, V_3 = span(e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4), span(e_1, e_2, e_3, e_5), span(e_1, e_2, e_3, e_6)$ for a dimension 6 example, and $span(e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4), span(e_1, e_2, e_3, e_5), span(e_1, e_2, e_4, e_5)$ for a dimension 5 example.

Thus, the only possible dimensions of the intersection are 2 and 3.